# Renewal Theory: Approximate the probability that we score 230.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, stochastic-processes, convolution

I am working on this renewal theory problem.

---

Suppose that we are a character in a video game collecting coins. Let $X_n, n \geq 1$ be the time between the $(n - 1)$th and $n$th coin collected, where each $X_n$ has probability density function

$$
f(x) = 
\begin{cases}
\frac{2\sqrt{2}}{\pi(x^4 + 1)}, & x > 0 \\
0, & x \leq 0.
\end{cases}
$$

Let $S_n = \sum_{i = 1}^n X_i$. Thus, $S_n$ gives the time we collect the $n$th coin. Let $N(t)$ be the number of coins collected by time $t$. Approximate the probability that we collect at least $230$ coins in $3$ hours.

---

I am working with *Probability Models* by Sheldon Ross as my text. So far, I think that we have

\begin{align}
P(N(3) \geq 230) & \iff P(S_{230} \leq 3) \\
& \iff P(X_1 + \cdots + X_{230} \leq 3).
\end{align}

We want to calculate $P(X_1 + \cdots + X_{230} \leq 3)$. I think this is supposed to be the n-fold convolution of the probability density, but I do not know how to do that. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: With some integration you'll find that $\mathbb{E}\left(X_j\right)=\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}$ and $\mathbb{V}\left(X_j\right)=\frac{1}{2}$ for all $j\geq 1$.

From central limit theorem
 $X_1 + \dots + X_{230}$ is approximately $\mathcal{N}\left(115\sqrt{2},115\right)$. Is this theorem available for your usage?

Comment: Yes it is! I’ll see if I can work out those facts.

Comment: I got the expectation of $X_j$, but I can not get the variance. I was solving $\int_0^\infty x^2f(x)dx - 1/2$. That's the right formula correct?

Comment: Yes, it is the right formula, and that integral is a bit nasty. To do it, you may want to use the fact that $$x^4+1=(x^2+1)^2-\left(x\sqrt{2}\right)^2$$